# Login from one Jhipster Application to another

Tags: spring-mvc, jhipster

I have two separate JHipster monolithic applications (say A and B) running on different ports.Both have same user information but different databases.I just want to login the current user from A into B whenever a request is forwarded from A to B.

Comment: Authentication is JWT

Comment: Do you use same JWT  secret?

Comment: Yes , But I have already tried using JWT Token to login.It only authenticates the user but does not login

Comment: You mean using the API with curl or swagger-ui? By "request is forwarded", I suppose you meant re-directed not forwarded, right? Your question does not provide enough details

Comment: You should check that JWT is stored in cookie in browser and also the domain of cookie is matching with your 2 apps urls.